# Applescript setting desktop picture to file in current directory

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm attempting to set the current desktop picture to an image in the current directory of the script. For example, if my folder structure is:

```
~/Documents/Scripts/DesktopImageScript/image.jpg
```

With the script in the same directory, I want to be able to set the desktop image to the image.jpg without directly referring to the folder structure. The code I am currently using to fetch the current directory is:

```
tell application "System Events" to set app_directory to POSIX path of (container of (path to me))
```

The issue isn't in that code as I can run the following command with the expected and correct results:

```
do shell script "echo " & app_directory
```

I believe the issue is in the code I'm using to set the desktop image:

`tell application "Finder"
    set desktop picture to POSIX file (quoted form of POSIX path of (app_directory & "/image.jpg")) 
end tell`

The error I receive when I try to run the script is:

`error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000`

Not really sure what could be causing the error or how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. The full script is below:

`tell application "System Events" to set app_directory to POSIX path of (container of (path to me))
tell application "Finder"
    set desktop picture to POSIX file (quoted form of POSIX path of (app_directory & "/image.jpg"))
end tell`

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using code from another answer on StackOverflow.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theDesktops to a reference to every desktop
    repeat with x from 1 to (count theDesktops)
        set picture of item x of the theDesktops to app_directory & "/image.jpg"
    end repeat
end tell
```